# Out of my 3 readFileSync one of them not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

One of my readFileSync arent executing  (my first time on stackOverflow)

Heres my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
const url = require("url");
const replaceItem = require("./modules/replaceItems");

const overview = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/templates/overview.html`,
  "utf-8"
);

// this line aint working
const cardPage = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/templates/card.html`, "utf-8");

const ProductPage = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/templates/product.html`,
  "utf-8"
);



const data = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/Dev-Data/data.json`, "utf-8");
const data_Dat = JSON.parse(data);

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const pathName = req.url;

  if (pathName === "/overview") {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-type": "text/html",
    });

    const cardsHtml = data_Dat.map((el) => replaceItem(cardPage, el)).join("");
    const output = ProductPage.replace("{%PRODUCT_CARDS%}", "cardsHtml");
    res.end(output);
  }
});

server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  console.log("I hear ya");
});
```

i see this btw if i do - console.log(cardPage) (Idk how to reply to comments) -

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <style>
        .beds_card-1 {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .beds_card-1 h3 {
            margin: 0;
        }
        
        .img {
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="beds_card-1">
        <h3>{%PRODUCTNAME%}</h3>
        <img src="{%SRC_LINK%}" class="img">
        <h4>${%PRICE%}</h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted cardPage placeholders to be replaced with the items in replaceItems.js file but the
cardPage readFileSync aint executing

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. What do you see if you do `console.log(cardPage)`?

Comment: @Barmar i just receive my html code

Comment: Then `readFileSync()` is obviously working. There's a different problem.

Comment: Please share `modules/replaceItems` code

Comment: @pierpy Here's the code for modules/replaceItems

`module.exports = (temp, product) => {
    let output = temp.replace(/{%PRODUCTNAME%}/g, product.name);
    output = output.replace(/{%SRC_LINK%}/g, product.src);
    output = output.replace(/{%PRICE%}/g, product.price);
  }`

Comment: @Barmar this is even weirder for me some of my html code from cardPage is being read but when it reaches the placeholders the rest doesnt load

Comment: Don't pupt code in comments, edit the question so it will be formatted readably.

Comment: When you call `replacePage()` with `map()` and `join()`, you're creating invalid HTML, because you get multiple `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` elements. You should only be duplicating the `<div>` that contains the template you want to fill in, not the entire HTML page.

Comment: @Barmar i changed the code in my card.html now its just a div but when i load it in the browser the only element that shows in Inspect is div not the other items

Comment: You need to move the other stuff to the original HTML.